# How to add some field to docusign template via rest api2 in PHP

Tags: c#, php, docusignapi

I need to add some fields to docusign template via rest api 2 in php.

Here is my php code snap.

```
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$templateRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole->setEmail("example@mail.com");
$templateRole->setName("Name");
$templateRole->setRoleName("Name");
$envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("[DocuSign PHP SDK] - Please sign this template doc");
$templateRole->setTabs(["tabs"=>[
    "textTabs"=>[
        "tabLabel"=>"test___label",
        "value"=> "$100",
        "xPosition"=> "100",
        "yPosition"=> "100",
        "documentId"=> "1",
        "pageNumber"=> "1",
        "locked"=> "false",
    ]
]]);

$envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles(array($templateRole));
$envelop_definition->setTemplateId("template Id");
$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
$options->setCdseMode(null);
$options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);
$envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, $options);
```

....
But i can't see tabs in my docusign when i 'm sending document with this template.
Please help me.

Comment: how is this related to c# ?

Comment: DocuSign templates are created from the DocuSign Admin Panel as far as I know.

Comment: The main point in this project is alwasy same like C#, PHP, Python, Java, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some PHP code that creates a template with tags, I copied it from (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-create-template) where we have it in different languages:

```
private function worker($args)
{
    # 1. call Templates::list API method
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
    $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $templates_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi($api_client);
    $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi\ListTemplatesOptions();
    $options->setSearchText($this->template_name);
    $results = $templates_api->listTemplates($args['account_id'], $options);
    $created_new_template = false;
    if ($results['result_set_size'] > 0) {
        $template_id = $results['envelope_templates'][0]['template_id'];
        $results_template_name = $results['envelope_templates'][0]['name'];
    } else {
        # Template not found -- so create it
        # Step 2 create the template
        $template_req_object = $this->make_template_req();
        $results = $templates_api->createTemplate($args['account_id'], $template_req_object);
        $template_id = $results['template_id'];
        $results_template_name = $results['name'];
        $created_new_template = true;
    }
    return [
        'template_id' => $template_id,
        'template_name' => $results_template_name,
        'created_new_template' => $created_new_template];
}
/**
 * Create a template request object
 * @return mixed
 */
private function make_template_req()
{
    # document 1 is a pdf
    #
    # The template has two recipient roles.
    # recipient 1 - signer
    # recipient 2 - cc
    #
    # Read the pdf from the disk
    # read files 2 and 3 from a local directory
    # The reads could raise an exception if the file is not available!
    $demo_docs_path = __DIR__ . '/../public/demo_documents/';
    $doc_file = 'World_Wide_Corp_fields.pdf';
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $doc_file);
    $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);
    # Create the document model
    $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
        'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    # Create the signer recipient model
    # Since these are role definitions, no name/email:
    $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
        'role_name' => 'signer', 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"]);
    # create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents
    $cc = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CarbonCopy([
        'role_name' => 'cc', 'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2"]);
    # Create fields using absolute positioning
    # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
    $sign_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
        'x_position' => '191', 'y_position' => '148']);
    $check1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
        'x_position' => '75', 'y_position' => '417', 'tab_label' => 'ckAuthorization']);
    $check2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
        'x_position' => '75', 'y_position' => '447', 'tab_label' => 'ckAuthentication']);
    $check3 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
        'x_position' => '75', 'y_position' => '478', 'tab_label' => 'ckAgreement']);
    $check4 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
        'x_position' => '75', 'y_position' => '508', 'tab_label' => 'ckAcknowledgement']);
    # Unfortunately there is currently a bug in the PHP SDK such that creating
    # a list tab is not yet supported via the SDK. You can use the API directly if need be, see eg010 file.
    # See https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/issues/58
    # Once the bug is fixed something similar to the following will be used:
    /* $list1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListModel (['document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
            'x_position' => "142", 'y_position' => "291", 'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size14",
            'tab_label' => "list", 'required' => "false",
            'list_items' => [
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Red"   , 'value' => "red"   ]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Orange", 'value' => "orange"]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Yellow", 'value' => "yellow"]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Green" , 'value' => "green" ]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Blue"  , 'value' => "blue"  ]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Indigo", 'value' => "indigo"]),
                new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem(['text' => "Violet", 'value' => "violet"]),
            ])*/
    $number1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Number(['document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "163", 'y_position' => "260",
        'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size14", 'tab_label' => "numbersOnly",
        'width' => "84", 'required' => "false"]);
    $radio_group = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RadioGroup(['document_id' => "1", 'group_name' => "radio1",
        'radios' => [
            new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio(['page_number' => "1", 'x_position' => "142", 'y_position' => "384",
                'value' => "white", 'required' => "false"]),
            new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio(['page_number' => "1", 'x_position' => "74", 'y_position' => "384",
                'value' => "red", 'required' => "false"]),
            new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio(['page_number' => "1", 'x_position' => "220", 'y_position' => "384",
                'value' => "blue", 'required' => "false"])
        ]]);
    $text = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text(['document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "153", 'y_position' => "230",
        'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size14", 'tab_label' => "text",
        'height' => "23", 'width' => "84", 'required' => "false"]);
    # Add the tabs model to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer->setTabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here],
        'checkbox_tabs' => [$check1, $check2, $check3, $check4], # 'list_tabs' => [$list1],
        'number_tabs' => [$number1], 'radio_group_tabs' => [$radio_group], 'text_tabs' => [$text]
    ]));
    # Create top two objects
    $envelope_template_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeTemplateDefinition([
        'description' => "Example template created via the API",
        'name' => $this->template_name,
        'shared' => "false"
    ]);
    # Top object:
    $template_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeTemplate([
        'documents' => [$document], 'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
        'envelope_template_definition' => $envelope_template_definition,
        'recipients' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients([
            'signers' => [$signer], 'carbon_copies' => [$cc]]),
        'status' => "created"
    ]);
    return $template_request;
}
```